# Value from state not there | React

Tags: reactjs

#### My Problem

I am using React and Apollo in my frontend application. When I login as a regular user I want to be navigated to a certain path, but **before** that I need to set my providers state with my `selectedCompany` value. However, sometimes I get my value from my provider in my components `CDM` and sometimes I don't, so I have to refresh in order to get the value.

I've tried to solve this, but with no luck. So I am turning to the peeps at SO.

#### My setup (code)

In my login component I have my login mutation, which looks like this:

```
login = async (username, password) => {
    const { client, qoplaStore, history } = this.props;
    try {
        const result = await client.mutate({
            mutation: LOGIN,
            variables: {
                credentials: {
                    username,
                    password,
                }}
            });
            const authenticated = result.data.login;
            const { token, roles } = authenticated;
            sessionStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            sessionStorage.setItem('lastContactWithBackend', moment().unix());
            qoplaStore.setSelectedUser(authenticated);
            qoplaStore.setUserSessionTTL(result.data.ttlTimeoutMs);

            if (roles.includes(ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN)) {
                history.push("/admin/companies");
            } else {
                // This is where I'm at
                this.getAndSetSelectedCompany();
                history.push("/admin/shops");
            }
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: loginErrorMessage(error) });
    }
};
```

So if my login is successful I check the users `roles`, and in this case, I will get into the `else` statement. The function `getAndSetSelectedCompany` look like this:

```
getAndSetSelectedCompany = () => {
    const { client, selectedValues, qoplaStore } = this.props;
    client.query({ query: GET_COMPANIES }).then(company => {
        selectedValues.setSelectedCompany(company.data.getCompanies[0]);
    });
};
```

So I am fetching my companies try to set one of them in my providers state with the function `setSelectedCompany`. `selectedValues` is what im passing down from my consumer to all my routes in my router file:

```
<QoplaConsumer>
    {(selectedValues) => {
        return (
            ...
        )
    }}
</QoplaConsumer
```

And in my provider I have my `setSelectedCompany` function which looks like this:

```
setSelectedCompany = company => {
    this.persistToStorage(persistContants.SELECTED_COMPANY, company);
    this.setState({
        selectedCompany: company
    })
};
```

And my `selectedValues` are coming from my providers state.

And in the component that has the route I'm sending the user to I have this in it's CDM:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { client, selectedValues: { selectedCompany, authenticatedUser } } = this.props;
    console.log('authenticatedUser', authenticatedUser)
    if (selectedCompany.id === null) {
        console.log('NULL')
    }
```

Sometimes I get into the if statement, and sometimes I don't. But I rather always come into that if statement. And that is my current problem

All the help I can get is greatly appreciated and if more info is needed. Just let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What if you await `this.getAndSetSelectedCompany();`: `await this.getAndSetSelectedCompany();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getAndSetSelectedCompany` is asynchronous and it also calls another method that does `setState` which is also async.

One way to do this would be to pass a callback to the `getAndSetSelectedCompany` that would be passed down and executed when the state is actually set.

changes to your login component

```js
  if (roles.includes(ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN)) {
      history.push("/admin/companies");
  } else {
      // This is where I'm at
      this.getAndSetSelectedCompany(()=>history.push("/admin/shops"));
  }
```

changes to the two methods that are called

```js
getAndSetSelectedCompany = (callback) => {
    const { client, selectedValues, qoplaStore } = this.props;
    client.query({ query: GET_COMPANIES }).then(company => {
        selectedValues.setSelectedCompany(company.data.getCompanies[0], callback);
    });
};

setSelectedCompany = (company, callback) => {
    this.persistToStorage(persistContants.SELECTED_COMPANY, company);
    this.setState({
        selectedCompany: company
    }, callback)
};
```

Comment: Thank you mister. You solved it. Never thought about adding a callback to it.